# Dynamic Find By In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So, I have a very simple bit of code that works great in Rails 2, but breaks in Rails 3.

In Rails 2 I have the following for displaying page contents using a viewer controller from the Page model:

```
class ViewerController < ApplicationController
show
  @page = Page.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

My viewer show view has the following:

```
<%= @page.body %>
```

My routes.rb file has the following to handle this action:

```
 map.view_page ":name", :controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show'
```

Here is the error I get in Rails 3 using this code:

```
undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

Now, I know the routes have to be changed in Rails 3, but what else am I missing to make this simple code work in a Rails 3 app?  I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  Thanks!

Comment: What's not working? Got any errors for us?

Comment: Try using `find_by_name!` instead. The `params[:name]` variable coming through may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan!  Adding the "bang" worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
match ":name", :to => "viewer#show", :as => "view_page"
```

Not tested not sure if it's match "/:name" or if ":name" is ok too.

Comment: Thanks Dinatih :)  Very helpful.  I had my routes already set very similar to your code, but it still wasn't working.  I needed the "bang" in my controller.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Rails 3 have got new routing sintax

```
get "/:name" => 'viewer#show'
```

Useful links:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/

**UPD**

Your error is because Rails can't find any Page with your `:name`:

- There is no any Page with this name
- There is no any :name at all in your `params` hash

Comment: That most likely would not fix his problem.

Comment: it might, the problem is that the :name parameter is nil when it hits the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database has the body field filled with something and it should work just like you have it.

domain.com/viewer/show?name=home